# How to grey out traces not selected in a parallel coordinate plot using the ‘parcoords’ package in R Shiny?

Tags: r, plot, shiny

I am using the R library ‘parcoords’ to create an interactive parallel coordinates plot. By default, when no selection along any axis is made, the plot shows all traces. When some range is selected across an axis only the traces within the selection window are visible and all other traces disappear. I was wondering if there is a way for the other traces to be just greyed out but still visible on the plot similarly to the parallel coordinate plot using the plotly package?

Thank you!

```r
library(shiny)
library(parcoords)
library(d3r)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
         
        ),

        mainPanel(
           parcoordsOutput("par_plot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$par_plot<- renderParcoords({
        data(mtcars)
        parcoords(mtcars, rownames = TRUE, brushMode = "1d-axes-multy", reorderable = FALSE,
                  color = list(
                      colorBy = "mpg",
                      colorScale = "scaleOrdinal",
                      colorScheme = "schemeCategory10"
                  ),
                  withD3 = TRUE)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to figure out something very similar which also works for me i.e. instead of grey out the traces that are not selected, make them more transparent so that they don't stand out compared to the selected ones. This is achieved by using the parcoords parameter 'alphaOnBrushed'. I set it to 0.15 and the plot looks exactly the way I want it in terms of emphasising the brushed traces.

```r
library(shiny)
library(parcoords)
library(d3r)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
         
        ),

        mainPanel(
           parcoordsOutput("par_plot")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$par_plot<- renderParcoords({
        data(mtcars)
        parcoords(mtcars, rownames = TRUE, brushMode = "1d-axes-multy",   reorderable = FALSE,
alphaOnBrushed = 0.15,
                  color = list(
                      colorBy = "mpg",
                      colorScale = "scaleOrdinal",
                      colorScheme = "schemeCategory10"
                  ),
                  withD3 = TRUE)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```